# Задать onTouchListener на каждый элемент ListView

Tags: android, listview, ontouchlistener

Имеется адаптер

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

В нем имеется метод:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = convertView;

     if (view == null) {
          view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

     Contact p = getContact(position);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_tv)).setText(p.name);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.num_tv)).setText(p.tel);

        number = p.tel;

    OnTouchListener listener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                fromPosition = event.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                float toPosition = event.getX();
                Log.i("log_tag","Номер = " + number);   
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    view.setOnTouchListener(listener);

    return view;
}
```

Суть в том, что при определенном движении на элементе списка (у меня это список контактов), мне нужно получить значение текстового поля этого элемента.
Как повесить onTouchListener на каждый элемент списка? Сейчас при нажатии на элемент в логе у меня вылезает значение текстового поля того элемента, который последним появился на экране при прокрутке списка.

Comment: Судя по Вашему коду - вылезает у Вас значение переменной number, которая перезаписывается при создании каждого item'a - поэтому и выводится всегда последний

Comment: Да, так и получается. Вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы выводился номер для того контакта, на который я нажал?

Comment: Всем спасибо, вопрос решился.
Всего-то надо было переместить строчку number = p.tel; внутрь onClickListener!

Answer (score 2):

```
...  // код в getView
ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.contactName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        viewHolder.picture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactPicture);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);

// обработчик нажатия

  public void onClick(View view) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder=(ViewHolder ) view.getTag();
        Intent intent=...
        intent.putExtra(..., viewHolder.id);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

// холдер
    private final static class ViewHolder {
        public String id;
        public TextView contactName;
        public ImageView picture;
    }
```